# lua mouse event handler

Tags: lua, mouseevent

I'd like to create an event handler in lua which can detect and locate mouse clicks (and ideally wheel movements) within a window, but can't find any way of doing it. 
Is there any way of doing it in lua, or would it be possible to create a hook somehow?

Events don't have to be reacted to immediately, so if there were some way of creating a table of mouse events which could subsequently be read from that would be fine.

I'm on ubuntu 14.04, and have Python available (if that helps). Thanks David

Comment: I have absolutely no idea if Lua is able to even start getting mouse clicks, where the pointer is, wheel movements, etc. I would personally use C++ for this, but if somebody can prove me wrong, and prove that Lua _can_ in fact do this, then I'll be surprised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure exactly what your requirements are, but there's a few options.

By far the easiest would be to use would be [LOVE](http://www.love2d.org) -- technically it's a sort of game framework that hosts Lua scripts but it displays a window and you can handle the events inside of the Lua runtime. Code to accomplish this would be roughly:

```
function love.mousepressed(x, y, button)
  -- do stuff here
end
```

---

More difficult but more Lua-centric might be something like [wxLua](http://wxlua.sourceforge.net/index.php) which should allow you to create and manage a native window against the wxWidgets library (N.B. I have never gotten this to compile and run on OS X)

There's a number of bindings like wxLua to other GUI frameworks. There's a [complete list](http://lua-users.org/wiki/GraphicalUserInterfaceToolkits) over at the lua-users wiki.